# xml schema xsd:all and one another element

Tags: xml, xsd

I have 3 elements all required but can be in any order and after them one element which is optional and maxOccours unbounded. How to write xsd?

```
<!-- pid is required, unique (positive) integer 
            (can be used as a key for persons);
            the name, surname, salary elts. can be ordered in any order -->
            <person pid="1">    
                <!-- name is required, non-empty string -->  
                <name>Pavel</name>   
                <!-- surname is required, non-empty string -->
                <surname>Novák</surname> 
                <!-- salary is required, positive number 
                 with 2 decimal places precision, e.g. 10000.50 -->
                <salary>200000.00</salary> 
                <!-- note optional element, repeatable, contains any string -->  
                <note>Poznámka</note>   
            </osoba>
```

Comment: Are all the required children really the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this be combination of choice (all orders) and sequence within sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The first three elements corresponds to an "all" model group, while the overall setting is a sequence.

As far as I know, XML Schema does not allow nesting an "all" model group inside a sequence model group.

The following schema validates a superset in which notes can be anywhere as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="surname" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="salary" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:all>
      <xs:attribute name="pid" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

From there, one can further fine-tune the strings to be non-empty and decimal values using type restrictions.

Comment: maxOccurs of elements can be set only to 0 or 1